# Terminal (bash?) / Docker: logic behind - and --

Tags: bash, docker, terminal

For three days I am learning to work with Docker.
During this I ran commands like

```
sudo docker run --rm -ti --net=example --name server ubuntu:14.04 bash
```

and

```
 nc -lp 1234
```

I was wondering why I have to use sometimes a `-` and for other commands a `--`
Is there any logic?

Regarding the topic of my question: I am aware that it is not a good topic. I am sorry for that. This question occurred while working with Docker but I do not know if the `-` or `--` thematic is more a terminal or docker topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the command. There are conventions, but none of them are followed universally.

In the Old Days, options were single letters. If an option took an argument, it could follow the option letter with or without an intervening space (`command -x foo` or `command -xfoo`).

Options that *don't* take arguments can be bundled, so `command -x -y` can be written as `command -xy`.  For many commands, even options that do take arguments can be bundled, with the last specified option taking the argument: `command -x -y foo` vs. `command -xy foo`. The `nc -lp 1234` in your question is an example of this; `l` and `p` are two different options. That could also have been written as `nc -l -p 1234`.

Commands from the GNU project can typically accept options either in the traditional short form and in a long form, where the option name is an entire word that can be abbreviated as long as the abbreviation is unique. For example, `ls` has a `-F` option to append a `/` to directory names and so forth. Gnu `ls` lets this be specified as `--classify`, or abbreviated as `--cl`.  To avoid ambiguity and for backwards compatibility, old-style single-letter options use a single `-`, while long-form options use `--`.

Finally *some* commands take options with long names introduced by a single `-`; the `find` command is an example of this.

The only real solution is to read the man page for the specific command you're running.

Answer (score 3):

A single dash can be followed by multiple single-character flags. A double dash is followed by a single, multi-character flag.

in your case

```
sudo docker run --rm -ti --net=example --name server ubuntu:14.04 bash
```

**flags:**

```
rm (multi-character)
t  (single)
i  (single)
net (multi-character)
name (multi-character)
```

,

```
nc -lp 1234
```

**flags:**

```
l (single)
p (single)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and sharing your knowledge! You helped me a lot :)

Comment: @Jim To answer the smaller question at the end of your question, this is not at all unique to Docker; a majority of unix/Linux programs have options that work this way.

Comment: It's not as consistent as you suggest. See my answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson It wasn't my intention to suggest that what I was describing  above is absolute law ... it is a convention and sometimes people follow it ... sometimes they don't. However, got to admit,  your answer is much more thorough .. So, good job! ;-)